# Pass arguments into docker container from docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to migrate from manually invoking docker like this:

```sh
docker run -v /tmp/bazel:/data -p 9090:8080 buchgr/bazel-remote-cache --max_size=1300
```

to using a `docker-compose.yml` file, but cannot seem to know how to pass the `--max_size` to the container from it:

```yml
version: "3"
services:
  worker:
    image: buchgr/bazel-remote-cache
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 10s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
    ports:
      - 9090:8080
      - 6060:6060
        #args:
        #- max_size=1300
    volumes:
      - "/bazel_cache:/data"

  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    stop_grace_period: 1m30s
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

What am I missing here? I've tried the `args: ..` bit but docker complains about it:

```sh
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml bazel_remote_cache
args Additional property args is not allowed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything you pass after the image name in `docker run` is interpreted as the "command" part, and you'd pass this in a `command:` field in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  worker:
    command: --max_size=1300
```

You can separately override the `entrypoint:` (equivalent to `docker run --entrypoint`) if you need to replace that field.

If you control the service, consider also making it possible to set these values via environment variables; this is generally easier to set at the deployment layer than providing command-line arguments.  If you can make the default main command be short, specifying `command: run_service --max_size=1300` as a complete command is also clearer here.